# access underlying socket using http.server

Tags: python, server

I have the following code to run a simple http server

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

host = "localhost"
port = 8881
server_class = HTTPServer
httpd = server_class((host, port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print("http server is running {}:{}".format(host, port))
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
httpd.server_close()
```

At some point in my code I'd like to access the underlying socket `s` of the server (which I assume has to acessible somehow) to do something like `s.getsockname()` for example. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it as `self.socket`, like so.

```
httpd.socket.getsockname()
```

See the source code of the base class [`SocketServer`](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/SocketServer.py#L405) for more info.

However, for this use case the proper way of doing it is `httpd.server_address`. In general, you should not try to use the raw socket. Also I would skip the `server_class` variable and just go `HTTPServer((host, port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)` to keep things simple.

Comment: The only reason why I needed it is because I wanted to run it on port "0" to find an available port automatically and then get the port it used with `httpd.socket.getsockname()[1]`. Do you know of a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Oh, not that I know of, know. Seems like a legitimate use of `.socket`

Comment: Remember to accept my answer if it answers your question